# Singleton for Host

Tags: c#, design-patterns

How to make a singleton for host, not for application only using  c#,.Net?  Something similar is possible to make via shared memory in C++

Comment: this question is about how to make it in c#. Rebecca edited and added a question to the end

Comment: Stand alone application, Windows Service or a web application running in IIS? Or a mix thereof?

Comment: @Albin: I'm interested in  Standalone application, but concurrent access in service is also good, IMHO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, what you need can be achieved in the following way: Use the singleton pattern in every application that needs access to the "machine-wide singleton". When a singleton object is created, it should try to connect via .net remoting to a "singleton server" on the local machine. If this fails, it can create one and act as a server.

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, indeed, i think the scheme is suitable.

Comment: Note that .NET Remoting is not recommended for new development according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k.aspx).

Comment: thanks to point that out. My active .net development time ended short before WCF.

Comment: Also note that the use of the singleton is somewhat restricted in the remoting world. The actual object can not be shared. Every object you "get" via remoting is marshaled and you get a copy. Though you can call methods on the remote object that are executed remotely and returns other objects.